# Why does the last if statement always execute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make the function terminate when the stop == false, but I'm not really sure how everything is getting executed from what my debugging alerts are telling me.

Code:

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(checkTabs);
function checkTabs() {

  var stop = true;
  chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows)
  {
    windows.forEach(function(window)
    {
      window.tabs.forEach(function(tab)
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < numWatch; i++)
        {
          if(tab.url.indexOf(watchList[i]) != -1)
          {
            stop = false;
            alert("(1)" + stop); //When the if condition is false, I somehow get this alert after the one below
            return;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

  alert("(2)" + stop); //I always get this alert first and it always reads "true"
  if(stop == true)
  {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timerOn = false;
  }
}
```

This block of code always executes - my first alert is always "true"; even when I set up my tabs in such a way that stop would be set to false, it first alerts "true" and then alerts "false":

```
  if(stop == true)
  {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timerOn = false;
  }
```

Why is this? I can see a pretty simple workaround to make my program work, but I'm curious as to why my function behaves so strangely: the bottom if statement seems to somehow execute before the statements in front of it...

Here's my manifest (though I doubt it's relevant) - the above code is part of my background.js script:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs", "background"]
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your `(1)` alert is inside a callback which means it is async, so your `(2)` alert executes first because the async call is not done yet

Comment: Ahhhh I forgot about that, that probably explains it...

Comment: `chrome.windows.getAll` callback function is **asynchronous**. Therefore, the code **outside** of it will run before the code inside.